# Why is the regular expression not working in this environment?

Tags: regex, windows, powershell, replace

Here is the code.

```
$fic= "G1"
$SS = "G2"
$Q=(gc $fic)
$L="_","\>","\\","^un$"
foreach($x in $L){$Q=foreach($y in $Q){$y=$y.Replace($x,"");$y};
             $lines =  $Q ;$car,$sanscar = $lines.Where({$_ -match '.'}, 'Split');
$car |Set-Content  $SS}
```

Here is a sample content fot G1.

```
<empty line>
<empty line>
_aunv \> unverse\\  
_mag \> arrivage\\

_apis \> charger\\  
_un \> chargement\\  
un  
un  
un  
un  

_abr \> bear\\ 
_abr \> Beer\\ 
_fin \> absorption\\
un  \> alpage\\



_  
_  
_  
\>  
\>  
\\

\\  
\>\>\>
\>
\>

_rak \> ancien\\
```

Here is the output.

```
aunv  unverse  
mag \ arrivage
apis  charger  
un  chargement  
un  
un  
un  
un  
abr  bear 
abr  Beer 
fin  absorption
un   alpage
<empty line>
<empty line>
<empty line>
<empty line>
<empty line>
<empty line>
rak  ancien
```

It is supposed to create empty lines by replacement and then to get rid of them. It works fine except that when the string to remove is given by a regular expression the removal is not done (^un$) and then there remains empty lines fefore the last line. It must be something I am not aware of; what's wrong in that script? How can it be made to work? ("" is not part of the content, it shows where is found an empty line in the content.)

Comment: `$y.Replace($x,"")` is not a regex replace method. Use `-replace`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question properly, the code should remove empty or whitespace-only lines, and also lines that contain just 'un'. Furthermore it should remove characters '_', '>' and '\'.

This can be done using some regular expressions:

```
$fic = 'D:\G1.txt'
$SS  = 'D:\G2.txt'

(Get-Content -Path $fic) -replace '^un\s*$|[_\\>]+' | Where-Object { $_ -match '\S' } | Set-Content -Path $SS
```

Result:

> ```
> aunv  unverse  
> mag  arrivage
> apis  charger  
> un  chargement  
> abr  bear 
> abr  Beer 
> fin  absorption
> un   alpage
> rak  ancien
> ```

Regex details:

```
                 Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
   ^             Assert position at the beginning of the string
   un            Match the characters “un” literally
   \s            Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)
      *          Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   $             Assert position at the end of the string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any)
|                Or match regular expression number 2 below (the entire match attempt fails if this one fails to match)
   [_\\>]        Match a single character present in the list below
                 The character “_”
                 A \ character
                 The character “>”
      +          Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code you cannot replace using regular expression using the `replace` method. You have to do `$y -replace $x, ""` instead of `$y.replace($x, "")`.

Comment: I just tried that (`{$Q=foreach($y in $Q){$y=$y -replace $x,"";$y}`) but I get nothing different.

Comment: No you have to use $y -replace $x, ""

Comment: If I use that, `{$Q=foreach($y in $Q){$y -Replace $x,"";$y}`, it doesn't work at all (no replacement and répétitions of lines (16 times with various combinations ot the elements to supress).

Comment: Using this instead, `{$Q=foreach($y in $Q){$y -Replace $x,""}` I get what I get with the initial code.

Comment: Oh, I described that in my question. Why are you misunderstanding it?